# Why won't R recognize data frame column names within lists?

Tags: r, list, vector

**HEADLINE**: Is there a way to get R to recognize `data.frame` column names contained within lists in the same way that it can recognize free-floating vectors?

**SETUP**: Say I have a vector named `varA`:

```
(varA <- 1:6)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

To get the length of `varA`, I could do:

```
length(varA)
#[1] 6
```

and if the variable was contained within a larger list, the variable and its length could still be found by doing:

```
list <- list(vars = "varA")
length(get(list$vars[1]))
#[1] 6
```

**PROBLEM**:
This is not the case when I substitute the vector for a dataframe column and I don't know how to work around this:

```
rows <- 1:6
cols <- c("colA")
(df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, 
                         nrow = length(rows), 
                         ncol = length(cols), 
                         dimnames = list(rows, cols))))
#   colA
# 1   NA
# 2   NA
# 3   NA
# 4   NA
# 5   NA
# 6   NA

list <- list(vars = "varA", 
             cols = "df$colA")
length(get(list$vars[1]))
#[1] 6
length(get(list$cols[1]))
#Error in get(list$cols[1]) : object 'df$colA' not found
```

Though this contrived example seems inane, because I could always use the simple `length(variable)` approach, I'm actually interested in writing data from hundreds of variables varying in lengths onto respective dataframe columns, and so keeping them in a list that I could iterate through would be very helpful. I've tried everything I could think of, but it may be the case that it's just not possible in R, especially given that I cannot find any posts with solutions to the issue.

Comment: Do you mean a construct like this? `list <- setNames(replicate(3, data.frame(x = 1:10), simplify = FALSE), paste0('df', 1:3))`

Comment: You can't use `get()` on an expression like `"df$colA"`.  `get()` only works on names.  You would need to use `eval(parse(text = "df$colA"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
> length(eval(parse(text = list$cols[1])))
[1] 6
```

Or:

```
list <- list(vars = "varA", 
             cols = "colA")

length(df[, list$cols[1]])
[1] 6
```

Or with regex:

```
list <- list(vars = "varA", 
             cols = "df$colA")
length(df[, sub(".*\\$", "", list$cols[1])])
[1] 6
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are truly working with a data frame `d`, then `nrow(d)` is the length of all of the variables in `d`. There should be no reason to use `length` in this case.

If you are actually working with a list `x` containing variables of potentially different lengths, then you should use the `[[` operator to extract those variables by name (see `?Extract`):

```r
x <- list(a = 1:10, b = rnorm(20L))
l <- list(vars = "a")
length(d[[l$vars[1L]]]) # 10
```

If you insist on using `get` (you shouldn't), then you need to supply a second argument telling it where to look for the variable (see `?get`):

```r
length(get(l$vars[1L], x)) # 10
```